# How use MultiThreading in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have example MultiThreading in VB. Net, I using thread to spider site,, I have a problem :

I have to 
syncLock to lock 
sql query select top 1 link from tblSite where process = 0 and i update process = 1 , 
End SyncLock

I spider content with links, and i update LastUpdate in DB, An Proces = 0...
..

I do it slowly, can i help about performance with multi thread. And i use to spider ?

Comment: Please expand, not clear what you mean (especially by "spider") or are trying to achieve.

Comment: spider as task ": i get Content in q links site.

Answer (score 0):

Async IO you must use. And sync table in process not, but server place lock let instead.

Comment: I have a answer, i used many object. A object using to one function...good luck